# How to get an entity's property composed by other properties from database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, null, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity :

```
public class T_compteBancaire implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private Long                   id_compteBancaire;

@Transient
private String                 ibanCodePays;

@Transient
private String                 ibanCleIban;

@Transient
private String                 ibanCodeBanque;

@Transient
private String                 ibanCodeGuichet;

@Transient
private String                 ibanNumeroCompte1;

@Transient
private String                 ibanNumeroCompte2;

@Transient
private String                 ibanNumeroCompte3;

@Transient
private String                 ibanCleRib;

//Only this property is stored in DB
@Column( name = "IBAN" )
private String                 ibanComplet;

public String getIbanComplet() {
    ibanComplet = ibanCodePays + ibanCleIban + " " + ibanCodeBanque + " " + ibanCodeGuichet
            + " " + ibanNumeroCompte1 + " " + ibanNumeroCompte2 + " " + ibanNumeroCompte3 + " " + ibanCleRib;
    return ibanComplet;
}

@OneToOne
private User             owner;

//Other getters and setters
}
```

The issue is when I retrieve my entity from db and call `getIbanComplet()` method the result is `nullnull null null null null null null`. 
I dont want to store the other properties to DB. How can I solve this issue?

I am using SpringDataJPA + Hibernate in Spring MVC application.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using native query. 
Here my solution :

```
public interface TcompteBancaireRepository extends JpaRepository<T_compteBancaire, Long> {

@Query( value = "select cb.iban from T_compteBancaire cb where cb.owner_id =?1", nativeQuery = true )
String findIBANbyOwnerID( Long ownerID );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the IBAN number first to each property. There are multiple ways to do this, e.g., in the setter method, create a new method to extract these properties after loading the entity or using a JPQL query using select new package.Class( ) where you have to split them e.g. with substring.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Isn't there another magic solution ? E.g. an sql request which will only return the IBAN as a String and then use Substring + Setters  to split.